# Creating multiple new instances from a one liner

Tags: scala, initialization, variable-assignment

In the second week lectures from the **Principles of Reactive Programming** class on Coursera, there was an example that contained this interesting piece of code:

```
val notIn1, notIn2, notOut = new Wire
```

What language feature is being used here?

This creates three unique instances (adding a println to the constructor prints 3 lines), so its *not* being translated to something like

```
val notIn1 = notIn2 = notOut = new Wire
```

The result of invoking `new Wire` doesn't return a tuple, so I don't think it's pattern matching. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) (4.1 Value Declarations and Definitions):

> A value definition **val** *p<sub>1</sub>, ..., p<sub>n</sub> = e* is a shorthand for the
>   sequence of value definitions **val** *p<sub>1</sub> = e*; ...; **val** *p<sub>n</sub> = e*.